# Reading Text File and Printing Graphic

Tags: java, file, input, output, graph-algorithm

I have the following text file with data in the following structure:
The first line is the height and width of a board.
Each subsequent line of this file contains four integers describing a block in the board: The height and width of the block (both greater than 0), and the row and column of the upper left corner of the block.
I want to write a program that reads the file and prints the board with all the boards on the console. Can anyone point me into the right direction?

The text file's content:

```
    5,4 
    2,1,0,0 
    2,2,0,1 
    2,1,0,3 
    2,1,2,0 
    2,1,2,3 
    1,2,2,1 
    1,1,3,1 
    1,1,3,2 
    1,1,4,0 
    1,1,4,3
```

This is the end result i intend to achieve One big board with ten small pieces on it of different sizes [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADOHR.png)
So far I have tried this code:

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class readInput {
       public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
         Scanner s = new Scanner(new 
       File("Fiepath"));
       ArrayList<Integer>blocklist=new ArrayList<>();
    while (s.hasNext()){
        if(s.hasNextInt())
        {
            blocklist.add(s.nextInt());
        } else {
            s.next();
        }
     }
     s.close();
     System.out.println(blocklist);
          }
      }
```

but it only prints [4] on the console: How can i get it to print all the lines and store them in an arrayList??Help

---

```
[4]
```

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Add a picture for the expected output of your example.

Comment: So, if the board dimension is 5 x 4, and the first coordinate is 2,1,0,0, then that means draw one large board of 10 x 4 starting at coordinate 0,0?

Answer (score 1):

For reading the file you may use Scanner, its easy to use but inefficient. Read line by line, you may want to use String functions like split to get the values from each lines and do some book-keeping to keep track of the data so you may want to have an array to keep track of all the squares. I would suggest that you keep creating Rectangle2D objects as you go over the file and keep storing them. When you are through with the file use the Swing API to to create a JFrame to display the squares however you like.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/primitives.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/start/

Comment: Thanks Ahmed, let me try that for starters